# Dropdownlist databind using another class?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

The Dropdownlist data binding using throw common function. In this have a problem in passing dropdownlist.

Error: Object cannot be set an instance of object

The code is below

**Aspx Page Code:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlagent1" CssClass="ParameterTextBox" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"></asp:DropDownList>

Protected Sub chkcity_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkcity.CheckedChanged
 ldstOption = //fill values here
 lobjGeneral.loadComboBox1(Me.ddlagent1, ldstOption.Tables(0), "No Data found")
End Sub
```

**General Class:**

```
Public Sub loadComboBox1(ByVal cbo As DropDownList, ByVal dset As DataTable, ByVal msgstr As String, _
                Optional ByVal visible As Boolean = True, _
                Optional ByVal enabled As Boolean = True, _
                Optional ByVal tno As Integer = 0, _
                Optional ByVal dmem As Integer = 2, _
                Optional ByVal vmem As Integer = 1)

        Try
            If (dset.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                cbo.DataSource = dset
                cbo.DataTextField = dset.Columns(dmem).Caption
                cbo.DataValueField = dset.Columns(vmem).Caption
                cbo.DataBind()
                cbo.SelectedIndex = 0
                cbo.Visible = visible
                cbo.Enabled = enabled
            Else
                dset = Nothing
                cbo.Text = msgstr
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Call CreateErrorLogFile("General", "loadComboBox", Err.Description)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: @rewinder: lobjGeneral.loadComboBox1(Me.ddlagent1, ldstOption.Tables(0), "No Data found")

Comment: dataset has data and before run this line me.ddlagent1 as dropdownlist object. After run that line its change to null object and also its not calling the function

Comment: Can you show where you are defining the lobjGeneral variable?

Comment: Top of the class: Dim lobjGeneral As New clsGeneral

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside your loadComboBox1 method, does it get hit?

Comment: i put breakpoint. Before that shows error!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method should have to get Dropdownlist reference

```
Public Sub loadComboBox1(ByRef cbo As DropDownList, ......
```

Comment: You need to declare your dropdownlist variable as reference type instead value type.

Comment: you mean same function work in page load, but not working on dropdown selection changed?

Comment: did you change ByVal to ByRef ? ByRef cbo As DropDownList?

Comment: @Muhammad: Its Ok i finish it. In page load end i set nothing to lobjGeneral object. that is problem !!